# How can I do a better job of warming up without wearing myself out?

Tags: warm-up

I know that it's important to properly warm up before doing exercise. However, the recurring issue that I have is that I'll go through basic movements similar to what I plan on performing, attempting to warm up, but it takes almost as long as the workout itself, and I'm actually tired at the end of it. I've tried following example warmups, but the effect is the same.

Is there any magic formula for deciding what to do and at what intensity?

Comment: What, specifically, is the exercise that you are warming up for?

Comment: @DavidScarlett: Currently, Capoeira and Parkour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you want to warm up depends vastly on the type of sport. It's hard to tell you what you can change since you haven't added any of your current ways of warming up, but I'll give it a go. (maybe you could add some in the comments?)

For some sports **dynamic or active stretching** works really well, I would assume this would work well for both parkour and capoeira since you will need flexibility to preform these sports.

In other sports you might want to do some light interval, for example before a cycling race. When you hit the gym you want warm up the muscle groups you're about to train with some of the exercises you're about to do at 50-60% of the weight you'll be working with.

Last but not least, **the way you want to warm up also depends on your level of fitness.** (example; when I workout in the gym and I'm working shoulders, I do muscle ups as a warm up while some people are working up towards doing just a single muscle up)